# What is ladir in noinst_libfoo_ladir?

Tags: c++, makefile, autoconf, automake, libtool

I created an example project called foo, its **configure.ac** is:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([foo], [1.0.0], [a@a.a])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([foo.cpp])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])
LT_INIT
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

and its **Makefile.am** is:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES = foo.cpp
noinst_libfoo_la_DATA = test
```

When I run `autoreconf -i`, I get:

> Makefile.am:3: error: 'noinst_libfoo_la_DATA' is used but
>   'noinst_libfoo_ladir' is undefined.

What is `noinst_libfoo_ladir`? I can’t seem to find documentation on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is this line, as indicated in the error:

```
noinst_libfoo_la_DATA = test
```

automake deals with [these variable suffixes](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Program-and-Library-Variables.html) when deciding how to build.  Note that suffixes ending in `_DATA` is not one of them.  However, it does recognize `_DATA` as being installed in a location (e.g. `data_DATA` is installed in `datadir`).  The location that `noinst_libfoo_la_DATA` would be installed to would therefore be in the variable `noinst_libfoo_ladir`, the definition of which does not exist in Makefile.am, hence the error.

So `ladir` is nothing.  It's just suffixing `noinst_libfoo_la` with `dir`, trying to find an undefined variable.  The same process applied to `data_DATA` would be `data` (strip off `_DATA` suffix) + `dir` = `datadir`.  In order to not get an error, you would need to define something like:

```
noinst_libfoo_ladir = $(datadir)/libfoo
```

in Makefile.am.  I'd call it something else since a `noinst_` prefix has a special meaning for other things in autotools (don't install).

Comment: _DATA variables are mentioned in the manual. Though that leaves a lot of information unsaid that makes the error make sense.  http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Data.html#index-_005fDATA

Comment: Yep, the second error is just a stupid error of mine, I will fix it in the question so that people don’t get sidetracked